# Gitlab auto pull

Tags: gitlab, gitlab-ci, devops, gitlab-ci.yml

I have repository in GitLab. and I have Test and Dev branches in this repository.
In Gitlab pipeline, I schedule a job to auto run Test branch pipeline every 24 hours.
in Test .gitlab-ci.yml I have

```
deploy:
  stage: deploy
  script:
    - git pull --ff-only origin Dev
  only:
    - Test
```

After merging Dev in Test, this part of code was removed. And next time Test branch pipeline could not pull from Dev branch, when pipeline run.

How can I pull code from Dev branch to Test Branch without losing the code `- git pull --ff-only origin Dev`  ?

Or maybe it is possible to have tow .gitlab-ci.yml on branch? (if yes, how GitLab should know which one of them be diploid first? )

Answer (score 0):

> Or maybe it is possible to have two `.gitlab-ci.yml` on branch

You would generally [create your `.gitlab-ci.yml` in the `main`/`master` branch](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/ci/quick_start/index.html#create-a-gitlab-ciyml-file).
Which means that `.gitlab-ci.yml` would not be impacted by merges between `Test` and `Dev`. Which is what you need.